# How to open multiple folders at once on spcific position without any program

Tags: windows-10, batch, script, files-folders

How I can open multiple folders at once on a specific position without any program.

Maybe using some script or something. I can't install a program like Window Manager or something

See here what I want this looks like:

[image]

Comment: Which operating system is this?

Comment: Im using windows 10

Comment: This is possible using 3rd software.. but need open the same windows with predictable name.

Answer (score 0):

A .bat file may do, containing eg.

```
start "c:\tools\Varnish image"
start "c:\Program Files\Customer data wo orders"
...
```

Comment: I know that but this only open folder. There is some way to put this on place (like on photo) after lunch .bat file?